# ASP.Net MVC MVCPaging error trying to filter results while using pager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I installed MVCPaging from NuGet (https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging)

I want to enable a search/filter on my recordset, as well as paging, so this is what I've come up with:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string str, int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;

        // Get initial recordset
        var items = db.Customers.OrderByDescending(a => a.OfferCreatedOn).Include(a => a.Offers);

        // check if searchstring has any value, and filter if so
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            items = items.Where(t => (t.CustomerName.ToLower().IndexOf(str.ToLower()) > -1) 
                || (t.OfferReference.ToLower().IndexOf(str.ToLower()) > -1)
                || (t.EmailAddress.ToLower().IndexOf(str.ToLower()) > -1)
            );
        }

        // Pass remaining list to the pager
        //
        // Error on the next line
        //
        items = items.OrderByDescending(a => a.OfferCreatedOn)
             .ToPagedList(page ?? 0, pageSize);

        return View(items);
}
```

However, I'm getting an error on the last line:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcPaging.IPagedList<FGBS.Models.Customer>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<FGBS.Models.Customer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?

Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the model in the view, as you do not get the IEnumerable, rather you get IPagedList, that, along with the customer list, exposes properties such as HasPreviousPage, PageNumber, PageCount etc..., which is what you use to implement the page navigation logic.

example:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Customer>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
}
@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("<", null, new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1})</li>
}
```

**Update**

sorry, didn't understand the error at first sight. 
the error there is that you define the `items` variable as a var, that means that it gets its type resolved at compile time, when it gets the first value. as you pass it a result of a query, it becomes of type `IQueryable<FGBS.Models.Customer>`, after that, you try to pass the result of ToPagedList, that is an IPagedList, and the runtime can not convert it implicitly, as you may get some data lost. try to use a different variable for that. or you could just:

```
return View(items.OrderByDescending(a => a.OfferCreatedOn).ToPagedList(page ?? 0, pageSize));
```

Comment: Hi - it's not in the view I'm getting the error, it's in the controller - thanks anyway,

Comment: Thank you so much @Igarioshka for taking the time to help a second time.  Your suggestion worked perfectly.  Now I just need to look over it carefully, and learn from it.  All the best, Cheers, Mark